# Find json in dom with :contains, replace each element (individually)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string, string-formatting

I have some server-side generated json string in a table, so I don't know what content might come up in it. I don't even know if there might be a JSON string or not. The table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Some Header</th>
        <th> Some Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Something </td>
        <td>    
            {"Something":true,"Something":false,"Somthing":true,"Something":false,"Something":true,"Something else":false,"Something":false}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>
            {"Something":true,"Something":false,"Something":true,"Something":false,"Something":true,"Something else":false,"Something":false}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to format each one of those json's strings into a formated table. I tried using `:contains(":true");` but the returning element looks like this:

{"Something":true,"Something":false,"Something":true,"Something":false,"Something":true,"Something else":false,"Something":false}{"Something":true,"Something":false,"Something":true,"Something":false,"Something":true,"Something else":false,"Something":false}

It returns the json's as expected, but I couldn't figure out a way to reference the containing element back to replace it with a formated table. I did a different function for another table where every json string had a defined sibling, so I referenced that. Here's that function:

```
var jsonTable = function(s){
    var search = "th:contains("+s+")";
    var container = $(search).siblings();
    var string = container.text();
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(string);
    container.text(" ");
    var nospace = s.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    container.append("<table class='mini-table' id="+nospace+"></table>");
    jQuery.each(obj, function(text, val){
        $("#"+nospace).append("<tr><td class='large'>"+text+"</td><td class="+val+"></td></tr>");
    });
    return true;
};
```

So, my question is:

How can I target a specific element found using :contains when it returns several elements? Any help or better way to do this is completely welcome.

Ps: Sorry if my english sucks, it isn't my native language.

Comment: Are you generating this markup? If so, is there a reason you're using the content of the element to transfer the JSON instead of using a `data-` attribute?

Comment: I have no control over the table markup and there's no way to know if it contains JSON or not server-side, that's why I'm trying to find it trough :contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. Code loops over each cell, checks if first character is `{` or `[` and if it is, assumes contents are json. Could also check last character also and use a `try/catch` block as well to avoid `JSON.parse` errors being thrown

```
$('td').each(function(){
    var txt=$.trim($(this).text());
    var reg=/\{|\[/;
    if(reg.test(txt.charAt(0)) ){
       /* text is probably json, should check last character also*/\

       /* would wrap this in try/catch for safety and additional validation that it is JSON*/
       var obj=JSON.parse( txt);

        /* "this" is td with json in it*/
        $(this).append('<span>This is json</span>')
    }  

})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jM2za/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: It worked, just had a short problem with 'this' in nested functions, just had to save it to a new var and changed the 'td' to a function argument as the container of the JSON changes. Thanks!